# Is there a way to know how many spirits are left in Adventure Mode?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I just completed light world and unlocked dark world, and I would like to clean up light world before I enter dark world.

How do I know how many spirits are left to find in Adventure Mode and how can I find them quickly? Is there some counter of sorts? Does the game tell me if I have completed the entire map?

Comment: If you zoom out the map, sublevel icons will have a star next to them once completed. Unfortunately, this doesn’t work for the overworld map.

Comment: I think there is a counter on the panel right after you select your save when you go into Adventure Mode. Now to find the total number of spirits in the light world...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the overworld, there's no real way to see which spirits you still need besides using the right thumbstick to browse around the map.

For dungeons however, indicated by the swirling icon on the minimaps (key: <kbd>L</kbd>), you'll know when all the spirits are gone when you see a star icon appear next to the dungeon icon.

[image]

Comment: I had a glitch happen where the Temple of Light was marked as clear, but I had only cleared the first room.